Optimize VPC Endpoints costs for development environment
I recently set up 5 VPC Endpoints to avoid using NAT Gateway with my ECS tasks (2 for ECR, 1 for S3, 1 for Cloudwatch Logs and 1 for Secret Manager), each endpoint is linked to only one AZ. At the end, the VPC Endpoint Hours cost the same as the NAT Gateway.
As the documentation says "Pricing per VPC endpoint per AZ ($/hour)", could I detach my VPC Endpoint from all my subnets outside the working hours to avoid VPC Endpoint Hours costs ? Will the costs of endpoints be 0 or just decreased ?
I want to create an SSM Document for this but I need to be sure of that this will reduce the cost, and don't find any documentation about this.
Thanks !
